# Find value from a string

Tags: php, regex, wordpress, preg-match

I have a string like below

```
include="3524,3525,3523"][/vc_column_inner][/vc_row_inner][/‌​vc_column][/vc_row][‌​vc_row][vc_column][v‌​c_video link="youtube.com/watch?v=pkBBzH"][/vc_column][/vc_row]
```

I just want to extract integer values from string 3524,3525,3523. The number of numeric values can increase I am using the below code

```
$matches = array();
$content1 = preg_match('/include="(.*)"/',$content1,$imagesmatches);
print_r($matches);
```

This gets the values and everything else i just want numbers. I know i am using wildcard but i need a expression to just extract numbers from it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on edited question you can use:

```
preg_match('/include="\K\d+(?:,\d+)*/', $content, $matches);

print_r($matches[0]);
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/oF1zG5/1)

Comment: include="3524,3525,3523"][/vc_column_inner][/vc_row_inner][/vc_column][/vc_row][vc_row][vc_column][vc_video link="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pkBBzH"][/vc_column][/vc_row]  from this strng i want to get only number like 3524,3525 nut the number of numbers in the string can increase i am using this expression preg_match('/include="(/[^\d]/)"/',$content1,$imagesmatches); but it gets everything along with number... Any suggestion

Comment: Thanks ... I have made the edit ... your help is much appretiated